# How can I turn a dataframe into a markdown vertical table?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, formatting, markdown

EDIT Answer:
There are two types of tables I needed. One was the regular Horizontal table view. For that, I just used the "to_markdown()" with the added code to removed the indeces.
For the vertical view I copied and pasted Ehsan's code below and it worked perfectly.

Now, I wanted to paste these in a nice view to my excel sheet. That would have taken a bunch of work and formatting very specifically, and it won't work out with the to_markdown(), since that changes the DataFrame to a string. To get it as an index, you can't use that function. You'd either have to take your existing DataFrame and figure out how to add new rows and columns, or: create an empty DataFrame with the proper amount of columns and rows, and fill it with the necessary "|" formatting. After that, you'd have to fill out the empty/correct cells with data from your DataFrame that contains the data. However, this is too much work, so instead I just copied the string over directly into the proper excel sheet using this code:

```
#Now we are going to save this loop's iteration into the proper Excel sheet
    file_source ='Source Used.xlsx'

    #load excel file
    workbook = load_workbook(filename=file_source)

    #Pick the sheet "Sheet Used"
    ws4 = workbook["Project X"]

    #modify the desired cell
    ws4.cell(row = 1, column = 1).value = newDataFrameWithStringFormat

    #save the file
    workbook.save(filename=file_source)
```

From here, anytime I wanted to update my markdown website, I could just pull from the Excel sheet's first cell. It doesn't look pretty, but it works.

### END EDIT

I have a table that looks like this:
df:

| Project 1 | Project 2 | Project 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| data 1 | data 2 | data 3 |
| data 4 | data 5 | data 6 |
| data 7 | data 8 | data 9 |

I want to edit this table so that it can work with, say, markdown, and be formatted well. However, to do that, I need to add a bunch of formatting to it (it basically needs to look the same as StackOverflow's table setup when writing this question). What function can I apply to it so that a new table is created that looks like this:

[image: Table with headers on the rows]

As you can see in this picture, the pipes and hyphens are each a new cell of data. Additionally, the Column HEADERS are at the beginning of the rows, since this is a horizontal format. How can I apply this formatting to dataframes of varying size?

This is what the new one should look like (I bolded the Project names myself): [image]

Now hypothetically, I can transpose the data and use to_markdown(), but that may still run into the issue of the top column being created as a column header. How can I avoid this by making a custom function to add in the pipes ("|") and hyphens?

Thank you!

Comment: to_markdown() function in pandas makes a decent work to make a markdown table out pandas data frames - check here, might help: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_markdown.html

Comment: Hey Ehsan, THANK YOU! I spent all that time doing complicated formatting, and it didn't work, but this works well (add in: (df.to_markdown(showindex=False)) to get rid of the index column)

However, there is a slight add-on to my question that will require real formatting. How can I make the column headers on the left side, as row headers, instead?

Comment: I think that's a problem with markdown tables - check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60995936/vertical-table-headers-i-e-headers-on-the-left-in-markdown based on their suggestion in these cases better to use HTML rather than pure markdown

Comment: The best I can suggest is to transpose the dataframe, set the name of new headers as empty (df.columns = ["" for i in range(len(df.columns))]) and then make the first row bold in markdown (** **).

Comment: Yeah... I can see that. I'll probably go the transpose route, since I can easily automate that process. I'll post the code here once I complete it so others can make it work.

Thank you so much for your help! I wish I could "Check" mark your answer since you helped me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A potential answer:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({"Project 1":["data 1", "data 4", "data 7"], "Project 2": ["data 2", "data 5", "data 8"], "Project 3": ["data 3", "data 6", "data 9"]})

df = df.transpose()
# remove header
df.columns = ["" for i in range(len(df.columns))]

# make the index bold - ** ** 
df.index = ["**{}**".format(idx) for idx in df.index]
# **Project 1**  data 1  data 4  data 7
# **Project 2**  data 2  data 5  data 8
# **Project 3**  data 3  data 6  data 9

print(df.to_markdown())
#|               |        |        |        |
#|:--------------|:-------|:-------|:-------|
#| **Project 1** | data 1 | data 4 | data 7 |
#| **Project 2** | data 2 | data 5 | data 8 |
#| **Project 3** | data 3 | data 6 | data 9 |
```

Will be like this:

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Project 1** | data 1 | data 4 | data 7 |
| **Project 2** | data 2 | data 5 | data 8 |
| **Project 3** | data 3 | data 6 | data 9 |

### Updated:

In case you want the csv version of the markdown table in your specified format, you can modify the string and save it as a csv file:

```
markdown_text = df.to_markdown() # from above code
markdown_csv= markdown_text.replace("|", ",|,")[1:-1].replace(",\n,","\n")
with open("results.csv", "w", encoding="utf-8") as fp:
    fp.write(markdown_csv)
```

The results will be (you can skip `**{}**`, markdown bold, in case you don't want it - just comment that part of the code):
[image]

Comment: Hey Ehsan, this is perfect. Once everything is finished I'll hit the check mark.

I am running into a slight issue. I'm trying to save the new markdown format into an Excel sheet, but the to_markdown() turns the dataframe into a nice big string, which means that I can't save it to an excel sheet. Do you know of any workaround to make this work? If not, I may have to manually add in all of those bars and hyphens, which is half the issue...

Comment: I will update the code - check the updated part (hopefully it will help)